# Generating Wordpress featured image in foreach loop, showing same image for multiple posts

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, youtube

Good evening. I've written a function to programmatically insert a Wordpress post for each of our YouTube videos, using a `foreach` loop.

Everything is working wonderfully, until I get to inserting the post thumbnail. I am using a function that automatically handles the uploading and inserting of a thumbnail, and associating it with a post (below):

```
function Generate_Featured_Image($image_url, $post_id) {
    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image_url);
    $filename = basename($post_id.'-'.$image_url);
    if (wp_mkdir_p($upload_dir['path']))     $file = $upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $filename;
    else                                     $file = $upload_dir['basedir'] . '/' . $filename;
    file_put_contents($file, $image_data);

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype($filename, null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($filename),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $file, $post_id );

    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $file );
    $res1 = wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );
    $res2 = set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $attach_id );
}
```

This function does work, but for some odd reason, it only uploads the image from the last video in the loop. For example, if I have 5 videos, 5 posts will be created. Each containing it's own specific information, but the post thumbnail will all be the image from the last (5th) video. None of them have their own thumbnail.

Here's a slimmed down verson of my function that creates the posts:

```
function createYouTubePost() {
    ...some other code...

    $JSON      = file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?order='.$api_order.'&part='.$api_part.'&channelId='.$channel_id.'&maxResults='.$max_results.'&key='.$api_key);
    $json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);

    foreach ($json_data['items'] as $data) {
        $video_id = $data['id']['videoId'];
        $video_title = $data['snippet']['title'];
        $video_description = $data['snippet']['description'];
        $video_thumb_url = $data['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['url'];
        $video_thumb_width = $data['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['width'];
        $video_thumb_height = $data['snippet']['thumbnails']['high']['height'];
        $video_publish_date = $data['snippet']['publishedAt'];

        $args = array(
            'post_title'   => substr($video_title, 0, strrpos($video_title, '(')),
            'post_content' => $video_description,
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'download',
        );

        if (!if_download_exists(substr($video_title, 0, strrpos($video_title, '(')))) {
            $new_post_id = wp_insert_post($args, true);

            if ($new_post_id == 0) {
                echo '<br>Could not create the post.';
                var_dump($new_post_id);
            }
            else {
                Generate_Featured_Image($video_thumb_url, $new_post_id);

                ...lots of code to update various post_meta fields...

                echo '<br>New post created.<br>';
                var_dump($new_post_id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see the media attachments and how they're all the same:

[image]

And here are the individual posts that were created:

[image]

As you can see, each image is assigned to it's respective post, but the image is the same.

I have even tried setting the filename of each picture with a unique ID so that they're all different, but that didnt help. I have also confirmed that the image url's that I am passing to the function are all different.

My question is, if I am using my function `Generate_Featured_Image()` in a `foreach` loop, and provding it with unique information, why is it only using the last picture in the loop?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went with another solution. Wordpress' `media_sideload_image()` function works and is a more straight forward solution for my situation.

Here is the function that I'm now using to assign a thumbnail to a post:

```
function generateFeaturedImage($image_url, $post_id) {
    // required libraries for media_sideload_image
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

    // $post_id == the post you want the image to be attached to
    // $video_thumb_url == the vimeo video's thumb url
    // $description == optional description

    // load the image
    $result = media_sideload_image($image_url, $post_id);

    // then find the last image added to the post attachments
    $attachments = get_posts(array('numberposts' => '1', 'post_parent' => $post_id, 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC'));

    if (sizeof($attachments) > 0) {
        // set image as the post thumbnail
        set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachments[0]->ID);
    }
}
```

Here's [the link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/3029/how-to-retrieve-image-from-url-and-set-as-featured-image-post-thumbnail?rq=1) to the stack exchange solution that I found.